# How to force typescript check destructured props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript doesn't check props when I use destructuring.

I've already tried strict flag of typescript

let's describe simple component

```js
const Component = (props: { foo: string }) => <div />;
```

next code will throw typescript error

```js
<Component foo="foo" bar="bar" />
```

but this no

```js
<Component foo="foo" {...{bar: 'bar'}} />
```

So how to force typescript to show error on both variants of code?

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IProps {
    name: string;
}
const Test = <T extends IProps>(props: T & Record<Exclude<keyof T, keyof IProps>, "Only props of Test">) => <div>HELLO</div>
const FakeProps = {name: "hello", age: 24};
const Test1 = <Test {...FakeProps}/> // failure because of age
```

Hope this helps, this should solve your problem this is a common trick to force excess property check on